# MoviePy crossfaadein transition

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm trying to work with [python moviepy](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/)

I find some snippet online to apply a transition when I concatenate videos, however it seems not working for me. What I'm doing wrong?
This is an extraction of the code :

```
clip1 = VideoFileClip("out.mp4")
clip2 = VideoFileClip("out.mp4")

clips = [clip1, clip2]

fade_duration = 1
clips = [clip.crossfadein(fade_duration) for clip in clips]

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, padding = -fade_duration)

final_clip.write_videofile("final.mp4")
```

If I run the script I receive the error : `VideoFileClip don't have the method crossfadein`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...

you should add the fade translation in this way :

Hi all,
maybe this snippet can help also other people :

```
from moviepy.video.fx.fadein import fadein
clip = fadein(clip, 0.2)
```

I hope this help...